# bootstrap 3 the navbar section

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have used another website's code which contains HTML, CSS, Bootstrap, and JavaScript for use with my own website. Unfortunately when I used this code another file in the nav-bar section of the code does not work.

How can I make this code work?

**CODE:**

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Halil Eren Ertan</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
               <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="about.html">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
   </div>
   <!-- /.container -->
</nav>

<!-- Probably the problem why nav-bar section does not work is not relevent after this line but I posted it maybe you want to look it. -->


<!-- Page Header -->
<!-- Set your background image for this header on the line below. -->
<header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url('/home/eren/workspace/web-tutorial/my little startup/DSC_1481.JPG')">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="page-heading">
               <h1>WELCOME</h1>
               <hr class="small">
               <span class="subheading">What are you thinking about my sharing? </span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</header>
<!-- Main Content -->

<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
         <div class="post-preview">
            <a href="post.html">
               <h2 class="post-title">
                        Kuralları Değiştirmenin İlk Kuralı
                    </h2>
               <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                        Problems look mighty small from 150 miles up
                    </h3>
            </a>
         </div>
         <hr>

         <!-- Pager -->
         <ul class="pager">
            <li class="next">
               <a href="#">Older Posts &rarr;</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>


<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
         <p>Want to make comment? Just write any name and write things that you have tought about the content. The comment which is writen last is shown at the top of the comments.</p>
         <!-- Contact Form - Enter your email address on line 19 of the mail/contact_me.php file to make this form work. -->
         <!-- WARNING: Some web hosts do not allow emails to be sent through forms to common mail hosts like Gmail or Yahoo. It's recommended that you use a private domain email address! -->
         <!-- NOTE: To use the contact form, your site must be on a live web host with PHP! The form will not work locally! -->
         <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
            <div class="row control-group">
               <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                  <label>Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                  <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row control-group">
               <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                  <label>Message</label>
                  <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                  <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
               </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div id="success"></div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<footer>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <ul class="list-inline text-center">
               <li>
                  <a href="#">
                     <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                            </span>
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="#">
                     <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                            </span>
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="#">
                     <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-github fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                            </span>
                  </a>
               </li>
            </ul>
            <p class="copyright text-muted">Copyright &copy; Your Website 2014</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</footer>
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="js/clean-blog.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Which bit of code isn't working as it should be? Do we need that entire snippet? Have you included all the necessary libraries to use bootstrap? And where's the appropriate CSS?

Comment: http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-clean-blog/   This link is the original website I used. I tried to personalize this for me and I copied and pasted it another page but as I said the nav-bar section did not work. I did not  change the css file but there are some files on original website such as named less and js files. I did not used these files. Can the problem relevent with these files?

Comment: For bootstrap to work, you **must** include the "bootstrap.css" file, the "boostrap.js" file **AND** link the jQuery library **BEFORE** "bootstrap.js"

Comment: Thanks, I solved my problem with your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must include bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css.

Put this at the top in your header section before any custom css styles or stylesheets you wish to apply:

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

And put this at the bottom of your html page body :

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Read more at http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: I don't. Thanks your helps.